# how to parse a line- the content inside quotes or a pattern using unix

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, split

I'm trying to grab content inside some formatted text. example

input in file:

```
i would like to say ("hi")

i am leaving, ("bye")

who is there? ("crazy cat")

I have a ("dirty dog that needs water")


//
```

How do i grab only the string that is in (" ").

I tried to parse it by space or by a string that has (" but i wouldn't be able to get the strings with spaces...

currently i'm using

```
 cat get_list.txt | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Comment: Do you need the result to be `("hi")` or `hi`?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o -E '\(\".*\"\)' get_list.txt
```

Should do it if you want to include the `("` and the `")`

If you don't want those, then you need the following:

```
sed 's/^.*(\"\(.*\)\").*$/\1/' get_list.txt
```

Explanation:

```
s/       substitute
^.*(\"   all characters from the start of the string until a (" (the " is escaped)
\(.*\)   keep the next bit in a buffer - this is the match I care about
\")      this signals that the bit I'm interested in is over
.*$      then match to the end of the line
/\1/     replace all of that with the bit I was interested in
```

(Note - I changed the `grep` and `sed` command in response to valid comments that a pipe wasn't necessary).

Comment: i tried to use -o, but it's giving me "grep: Unknown option -o" "Usage: grep [-clqinsvxEF] [-bI] [-e pattern] [f patternfile] [pattern] [file].... "

Comment: Which distro do you have and wich version ? oO

Comment: I'm using msk toolkit for win32. file version 5.1.1.14

Comment: both `grep` and `sed` can be executed on files, so `cat` is useless here

Comment: try my second version then... The `-o` option means "return the bit that matched instead of the whole line". Apparently your grep doesn't have it.

Comment: @costiCiudatu - agreed. I was trying to mirror the syntax Lili had used to help in understanding.

Comment: the sed command works, but I'm having trouble with inputing _(" infront of the word and ") at the end?

Comment: What do you mean by "trouble with inputing"? Please describe what you do and what happens- I can't figure it out from your description, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using [look around regex techniques](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) :

```
$ grep -oP '\("\K[^"]+(?="\))' file.txt
bye
crazy cat
dirty dog that needs water
```

Or with a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) portable solution still using [look around regex techniques](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /\("\K[^"]+(?="\))/' file.txt
```

Or simply :

```
cut -d'"' -f2 file.txt
```

Comment: Added perl portable solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the text between double quotes (without the quotes themselves), you can use *awk*:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' get_list.txt
```

Comment: Can you modify this to match `("` and `")`? That's how I read the problem statement...

Comment: `awk -F\" '{print "(\"" $2 "\")"}' get_list.txt` -- but in this case I wouldn't see `awk` as the best fit any more...

Comment: I believe that puts `("` and `")` around the match (like my original `grep -o`). But what if you just want to get the bit inside those two character sequences... like the `sed` in my answer. I wonder if there isn't a more compact way to do it. I suspect you would know how to...

Comment: for some reason, i'm not able to use this command. it gives me an error: "awk: syntax error "contents of { } or \{ \} invalid" in /\ ' {print $2}' get_list.txt".... I do need the (" and ") in front and back of it.